# CXF JAX-WS on WebSphere 7 doesn't appear in the admin console

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws, cxf, java-ee-5

I'm using the CXF's wsdl2java (through maven codegen plugin) to generate sources from wsdl (top-down) of a jax-ws web service.
Everything is fine till I have to deploy on WebSphere Application Server 7.
So, I made some adjustments according to various documentation found on the internet.
Now my deployed jax-ws (with frontEnd forced to 2.1) works fine.

The problem now is that I don't see any trace of the web service contained in my web module from the WAS admin concole (nor client, nor provider... nothing at all).

This situation prevents me to apply Policy Sets and configure WS-Security from the admin console.

My questions are:

- what does prevent a working web service to be shown in the admin console?
- if I cannot see it in the admin console: how to configure policy sets without the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, if you are using a 3rd party JAX-WS library on WebSphere, neither the client nor the provider will not show up in the admin console, and you won't be able to configure it to use the WS-Security and other stuff that comes with WAS.

Read the official doc [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't find that link. It's useful to know from an official IBM document that WebSphere AS doesn't fully support non IBM tools, even if they are quite common ones.